# how to Unwrap wrapped PL SQL Code using script?

Tags: plsql, unwrap

does anyone know how to unwrap pl/sql code? I use https://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/ website to unwrap code. it is working but I prefer to do it myself. if anyone know the java code etc. to do this process on my computer.
Thanks